# Complex pandas rows merging keeping order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Let's assume the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "IDs": [
            ["A","C",],
            ["B"],
            ["A", "B"],
            ["A","C", "D"],
            ["B", "E"],
        ],
        "values": [[1, -3], [1], [2, -2], [4, 1, 3], [2, 5]],
        "timestamp":[
        pd.to_datetime("2022-01-01"),
        pd.to_datetime("2022-01-01"),
        pd.to_datetime("2022-01-02"),
        pd.to_datetime("2022-01-03"),
        pd.to_datetime("2022-01-03"),
    ],
    },
)
```

```
    IDs         values      timestamp
0   [A, C]      [1, -3]     2022-01-01
1   [B]         [1]         2022-01-01
2   [A, B]      [2, -2]     2022-01-02
3   [A, C, D]   [4, 1, 3]   2022-01-03
4   [B, E]      [2, 5]      2022-01-03
```

The idea is to merge rows with a similar timestamp while keeping the IDs sorted and inserting the corresponding values at the right place such that the desired result would be:

```
    IDs             values          timestamp
0   [A, B, C]       [1, 1, -3]      2022-01-01
1   [A, B]          [2, -2]         2022-01-02
2   [A, B, C, D, E] [4, 2, 1, 3, 5] 2022-01-03
```

Any idea on how to do that effectively?

FYI: In my application only a very small percentage of rows have duplicated timestamp.

Comment: Don't store your data like this, explode your ID and values columns and you don't need to bother with this kind of duplication.

Comment: Well I have it exploded at first and then obtain it with a groupby(timestamp).agg({values:list}). But since the df is huge, I use multiprocessing and do the groupby on chunks. And depending where the original df is chunked then I sometime obtain those duplicates. So yeah one approach would be to have a "smart chunking" with no common timestamp between each chunks... But was wondering if there is another solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) here. Just define a function that takes a sub-dataframe: for each unique timestamp, explodes the lists into rows, sorts by the `IDs`, and aggregates everything back to a list:

```py
def f(df):
    return (df[['IDs', 'values']]
            .explode(['IDs', 'values'])
            .sort_values('IDs')
            .agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()]))
    
df.groupby('timestamp').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```